# Python Turtle - Error with turtle.begin_fill() and turtle.end_Fill()

Tags: python, colors, turtle-graphics

I'm in a high school computer science class and I can't seem to find the correct placement/usage for turtle.begin_fill() and turtle.end_fill() to color in the shape I'm drawing. I've tried moving those two around and I keep getting this error:

```
TypeError: begin_fill() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Here's my code:

```
side_number = int(input("How many sides should the polygon have?"))
side_length = int(input("How long should the sides be?"))
side_color = (input("What color should the sides be?"))
fill_color = (input("What color should fill the shape?"))
import turtle
wn = turtle.Screen()
john = turtle.Turtle()
john.color(side_color)
for i in range(side_number):
    john.begin_fill(fill_color)
    john.forward(side_length)
    john.left(360/side_number)
    john.end_fill(fill_color)
```

Comment: ...[`turtle.begin_fill`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.begin_fill) *doesn't take any arguments* (except for the implicit first `self` argument). What are you expecting `fill_color` to do?

Comment: Fill the shape drawn with a color. Am I misunderstanding what it's function is? The tutorial I'm using doesn't explain what begin.fill and end.fill do but the assignment asks to use them. How would I go about filling the shape in with a color?

Comment: `begin_fill` signals to the interpreter, "hey, I'm about to start drawing a shape" and `end_fill` signals to the interpreter, "hey, I finished drawing my shape, please fill it in now". Just using those two should be sufficient, provided you specify a fill color before hand and call them at the right times, as indicated in my post

Comment: @RialJohnson yes, probably. Why don't you try reading the documentation I just linked?

Comment: @Kevin Thank you, your explanation cleared up a lot of confusion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`begin_fill` and `end_fill` don't take any arguments. You can specify fill color as the second argument to `turtle.color`. Additionally, `begin_fill` and `end_fill` should go outside the loop, because they should be called once per polygon rather than once per line.

```
side_number = int(input("How many sides should the polygon have?"))
side_length = int(input("How long should the sides be?"))
side_color = (input("What color should the sides be?"))
fill_color = (input("What color should fill the shape?"))
import turtle
wn = turtle.Screen()
john = turtle.Turtle()
john.color(side_color, fill_color)
john.begin_fill()
for i in range(side_number):
    john.forward(side_length)
    john.left(360/side_number)
john.end_fill()
```

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense now and does what I need it to do!